# I am using GN_MUSIC_SDK_IOS for recognise audio, and than i wants to map that song in itunes.

Tags: ios, gracenote

I am developing one app in which i am using **GN_MUSIC_SDK_IOS**, to recognise audio, i got this, now i wants to search this song in itunes and wants preview of the song same like shazam, and wants to give buy the song from itunes, does any one knows how it is possible.

I found some where that it is possible in commercial licence and contact to gracenote sales team, but i don't get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need a commercial license to access the data which can link you to the content on iTunes. Please visit https://developer.gracenote.com/plans and request for Accelerator Plan, and we can work with you from there.